# XML Schema Creation Error - What is JAXB Doing?

Tags: web-services, xsd, jaxb, cxf

I'm working on a project that involves a simple web service, and have had a slew of [little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195034/server-side-xml-validation-with-cxf-webservice) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222770/schema-errors-and-cxf).  It's an Apache CXF webservice (using JAX-WS, over SOAP). The service itself is pretty simple: receive a request, insert the request into a database, and return whether the insert was successful. I'd like to rely on XML validation to enforce a number of constraints on the request.

Full XML validation is very important to this project.  So far, I've been unable to properly validate, though my service otherwise functions.

I'm pretty sure it all boils down to this error, which is preventing validation.

```
Feb 8, 2010 4:47:14 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils createSchema
WARNING: SAXException for newSchema() on 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:905)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1393)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1763)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1492)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:442)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:435)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:491)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:1802)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler.java:1757)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:909)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:569)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:485)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils.createSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:666)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils.getSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.setSchemaInMessage(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.getDataReader(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.getDataReader(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:406)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:178)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Feb 8, 2010 4:47:14 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils createSchema
WARNING: Schema for: http://myproject.com/ws/schema
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns1="http://myproject.com/Schema.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://myproject.com/ws/schema" version="1.0">
<xs:import namespace="http://myproject.com/Schema.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="InvalidDataFault" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="RequestHeader">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="CourtID" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
<xs:element name="SecurityFault">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="court" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
<xs:element name="uploadData">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="ns1:DataPackage"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
<xs:element name="uploadDataResponse" type="xs:anyType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you can try with the latest CXF snapshots?   There was a bug in this area that was fixed last week related to creating schemas for validation from relatively large schemas.   The fix for that may solve this as well.

Comment: The 2.2.7 snapshot got rid of the newSchema errors- but doesn't seem to be validating.  I'm going to give 2.3 a shot now.