# How to override inbound message validation using Apache CXF?

Tags: java, validation, cxf, customization

When I input non-numeric content for a integer field, I get a fault message:

> “Not a number: 0.012A”.

Is there a way to output custom error messages, when unmarshalling for schema validation?

I am using Apache CXF 2.6.1 with

```
<entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" ></entry>
```

in cxf-spring.xml.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a number: 0.012A at com.jiemai.jmservice.handlers.ValidationEventHandler.handleEvent(ValidationEventHandler.java:19)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl$WSUIDValidationHandler.handleEvent(DataReaderImpl.java:78)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:655)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:691)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:687)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.handleParseConversionException(Loader.java:271)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:69)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:514)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:338)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:216)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:185)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:784)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:97)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$1.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:812)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:810)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:644)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:108)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:122)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:193)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:129)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:187)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:110)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195034/server-side-xml-validation-with-cxf-webservice

Comment: Tks,But i need more detailed and customizable messages.How should i do?

Comment: Using that approach you can add whatever messages you want.

Comment: I have seen, The feeling is not able to completely customize